# Genesis build order

Tags: genesis, hook

From what I see in the code, the Executive pallet controls the hook order via one of the passed parameters `AllPallets, AllPalletsReversed, etc.` that depend upon the declaration order in `construct_runtime!`.

I'm finding it difficult to figure out, what determines the Genesis build order, e.g. balances before staking. Is it purely dependent also on the declaration order in `construct_runtime!`? If yes, is it possible to somehow change the order as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of building genesis is the same as the declaration order in construct_runtime. I don't think you can change that without touching construct_runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Could you also perhaps point me to the code in `construct_runtime!` macro that is responsible for the generation of genesis execution/ordering?

Comment: One of the chain runtime types that construct_runtime expands and creates is called GenesisConfig for which the trait BuildStorage is implemented and there it goes over another runtime type called `AllPalletsWithSystem` which is a tuple constructed of all the pallets according to their declaration order. Have a look at: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.30/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/config.rs#L82-L95
Finally when the client builds the chain-spec it uses that GenesisConfig type from the runtime.